# jqgrid search with loadonce

Tags: java, json, jqgrid

i'm having a problem with jqgrid searching. my code works perfectly with add, edit, delete except searching. Once I load it the data shown fine, but if I click find button, it never does anything.
I have been looking for it everywhere but I can't find what's wrong. If I use `loadonce : true` then searching works but now having problem with paging and sorting the grid. I wanna make it work perfectly with paging, sorting, and searching.

here's my code.

```
$("#material_list").jqGrid({
            url:"MY URL",
            editurl:"MY URL",
            mtype:"post",
            caption:"LIST",
            datatype:"json",
            height:"auto",
            jsonReader : { 
                  root: "rows", 
                  page: "page", 
                  total: "total", 
                  records: "records", 
                  repeatitems: true
              },
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[5,10,15],
            colNames:["PROD_CODE","PROD_NAME","COMP_CODE","UNIT","STANDARD","USEFLAG"],
            colModel:[
                      {name:"PROD_CODE", index:"PROD_CODE", editable:true},
                      {name:"PROD_NAME", index:"PROD_NAME", editable:true},
                      {name:"COMP_CODE", index:"COMP_CODE", editable:true},
                      {name:"UNIT", index:"UNIT", editable:true},
                      {name:"STANDARD", index:"STANDARD", editable:true},
                      {name:"USEFLAG", index:"USEFLAG", editable:true}
                      ],
            pager:"#pager",
            autowidth:true,
            viewrecords:true,
            //loadonce:true,
        });

$("#material_list").jqGrid(
                "navGrid",
                "#pager",
                {search:true, edit:true, add:true, del:true},
                {closeAfterEdit:true, reloadAfterSubmit:true},
                {closeAfterAdd:true, reloadAfterSubmit:true},
                {reloadAfterSubmit:true}
        );
```